# datatable accessing via jquery object or API

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

i have problem like this
first i try to initialize datatable like this

```
var oTable = table.dataTable();
```

my script run well but i can't using `datatables ajax reload function`

```
oTable.ajax.reload(null, false);
```

reference by [this link](http://datatables.net/manual/api#Accessing-the-API)

it's seem i must accesing dataTables via API, so i change my initializing like this

```
var oTable = table.DataTable();
```

the problem is `fnUpdate`, `fnAddData`, and so on not working if i access it via API...and i used it alot (for inline editing datatable)

my question is

1. is there other reload function datatable which i can use if i access dataTables via jquery object
2. is there similiar function to replace function like `fnUpdate` if i acces dataTables via API?

Answer (score 1):

i solved this with add `.api` after initializing dataTables

in reference

```
$( selector ).dataTable().api(); == $( selector ).DataTable();
```

so i try this and working

```
oTable.api().ajax.reload();  == oTable.ajax.reload();
```